# While reading data from a stream, why does my program hang?

Tags: android, file, inputstream

While reading data from a stream I am writing to a newly created temporary XML file. But the program hangs.

What have I missed here?

```
if (deviceSocket.isConnected()) {
  OutputStream os = deviceSocket.getOutputStream();
  os.write(xmlStr.getBytes());
  os.flush();

  // Read Response from Socket
  respFromDevice = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(deviceSocket.getInputStream()));
  FileWriter fileWriter = null;
  // Write into temp xml file
  String response;
  while ((response = respFromDevice.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(response);
    File newTextFile = new File("tmp.xml");
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
    fileWriter.write(sb.toString());
    //Files.write(Paths.get("temp.xml"), sb.toString().getBytes()); 
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Improved grammar and code formatting for readability

Comment: What do you mean that the program hangs? And what does the XML file look like during the process?